# Django: ValueError Table allauth_socialapp does not exist

Tags: python, django, rest, django-allauth

I successfully followed [this](http://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-user-authentication-tutorial/) tutorial and everything seemed to be ok. I then created a Profile model and managed to create it's objects through POST requests and through the admin panel. I then created signals so the profile could be created as soon as the user registered. After some trial and error I finally made it and decided I'd flush the database. When I tried to do so and ran python manage.py flush I got this error:

```
raise ValueError("Table %s does not exist" % table_name)
ValueError: Table allauth_socialapp does not exist


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\flush.py", line 49, in handle
    allow_cascade=allow_cascade)
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 16, in sql_flush
    seqs = connection.introspection.sequence_list() if reset_sequences else ()
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 118, in sequence_list
    sequence_list.extend(self.get_sequences(cursor, model._meta.db_table, model._meta.local_fields))
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\introspection.py", line 96, in get_sequences
    pk_col = self.get_primary_key_column(cursor, table_name)
  File "C:\Users\arthu\Desktop\dev\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\introspection.py", line 196, in get_primary_key_column
    raise ValueError("Table %s does not exist" % table_name)
ValueError: Table allauth_socialapp does not exist
```

I already tried doing python manage.py migrate for each of the installed apps but nothing seems to work and already tried removing the Profile model and the receiver it is using but that doesn't solve the problem. Also tried deleting the sqlite file and all the migrations but it didn't help.

My **models.py** file looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('Male', 'Male'),
    ('Female', 'Female')
)

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
interests = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user}'s Profile"


@receiver(user_signed_up)
def user_registered(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    print(f"Created profile for {   user}")
    Profile.objects.create(user=user)
    """Creates the Profile after user registers"""
```

and my **settings.py** file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'core'
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
SITE_ID = 1
```

Can someone please help me with this? I have no idea what I'm supposed to do and couldn't really find the answer online.

Comment: Yes I did, Willem. Makemigrations returns "No changes detected" and Migrate returns "No migrations to apply",

Comment: Try dropping and recreating your database

Comment: Doing so didn't help

Comment: What happened when you ran `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, core, sessions, sites.

 And all the migrations it ran were successfull

Comment: Can you share the traceback for the error?

Comment: Just edited the main post with the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply solved this by adding `'allauth.socialaccount'` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` and doing the migrations. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try python `manage.py makemigrations AppName`

If this didnt work you can delete `migration folder` and your `database` and try.

Comment: Already tried doing so. After doing it I can makemigrations and migrate but cant flush. It gives me the same error